# Is it possible to return value from Spring AspectJ?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm returning value from my `controller`. Let it be `ResponseEntity<String>` type.

Controller returns:

```
new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"msg\":\"success\"}",HttpStatus.OK);
```

Following value goes to my `spring aspect`. I am receiving this object in following code:

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "somePointcut()",returning = "retVal")
public ResponseEntity<String> adviceTest3(Object retVal) {

    //here i have access to controller's object

    return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"msg\":\"changed value within aspect\"}",HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I'm aware that there `is @AfterReturning`. Is it any way manipulate data and achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `@AfterReturning`, no. Quote from the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop-api.html#aop-api-advice-after-returning)

> An after returning advice has access to the return value (**which it cannot modify**), invoked method, methods arguments and target.

You could use [@Around](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice) instead.